# Сохранение текста из txt в переменную bat/cmd

Tags: cmd, bat, txt

Есть txt файл с текстом (например "Information"). Как сохранить этот текст в переменную в bat/cmd?

Comment: Следует помнить, что сохранение текста с переводом строки в переменную - это специфическая задача. Существует и ограничение в длину переменной (вроде бы до 32000 символов, но это не точно). Поэтому иногда проще перенаправить вывод текста в поток (pipe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo Off
:: hi.txt - файл с текстом
::content - переменная, куда запишется текст
set /p content=< hi.txt
:: вывод содержимого
Echo %content%
```